# How to filter data in Thymeleaf table

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, dandelion

I'm a new Thymeleaf developer (Spring-Boot 2.1.5 environment).
I want to implement filtering over a list from an Input. When I enter the name of the client in the input it appears on a table (without submit button).

```
<form th:action="@{/clientslistbypage}" method="get" th:object="${Clients}" class="form-inline"  >
<input type="text" name="client" th:value="${client}"  id="clientSearch"     >
<!-- <input type="submit" name="clients" th:value="Search">-->
</form>
```

I tried the Projection and Collection function but I do not know how to dynamically assign the input value to the Collection formula.(${Clients.?[firstName >='here i want to insert the value of the Searche Input']})

```
<tr th:each = "c: ${Clients.?[firstName >='']}"  >
<td  th:text = "${c.id}"></td>
<td  th:text = "${c.firstName}"></td>
<td  th:text = "${c.LAST_NAME} "></td>
</tr>
```

I tried DANDELION but unfortunately, do not run under Spring-Boot 2.1.5.

any proposal, tutorial, or example is welcome

Comment: Not sure if I understand your problem correctly. But `jquery UI autocomplete` might solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. in the absence of a native solution of thymeleaf or dandelion, I will use JQuery UI autocomplete + JSON to search
do you have any example?

Comment: you can find tons of example if you just google.